# I don't have a phone and I want to start a new Whatsapp account on my PC

Tags: google-play-store, exchange

I do not have a phone and I wanted to open a new whatsapp account.
is this possible?
I have never made an account before and my friend suggests me to use whatsapp,
as I do not have a phone or any previous account this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use WhatsApp without a smartphone. From the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/28080003/?category=5245235):

> #### Minimum requirements to enjoy WhatsApp Web
>
> - You need to have an active WhatsApp account on your phone.
> - You need to have a stable internet connection on both your phone and your computer.
> - You need to use the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari or Edge as your web browser on your computer.

The account is tied to your phone number, so you can't borrow a friend's phone to set up the account either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

There is a way to use WhatsApp or any other Android app, on a PC using [BlueStacks](http://BlueStacks.com).

All you have to do is [download](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-run-bluestacks,review-1912.html) the BlueStacks app onto your computer, sign in to your Google account, go to the play store, and download WhatsApp.

After downloading WhatsApp, go thru the regular registration process. If you don't have a phone number of your own, you can register for a free number with [Google voice](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/7207482?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and use it for your WhatsApp account.

I have seen this work perfectly for others, let us know how it goes for you.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Only real numbers can be registered with Whatsapp!

Comment: @esqmo_ Yes I'm running a Google voice number on WhatsApp. And i know others who are doing the same. I know that they will block 'online' numbers. But not Google voice

Comment: Okay, never tried that. But this works only for people living in the US not outside right?

Comment: @esQmo_ it works internationally. But it would give you an American number, which is not a problem for WhatsApp

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, you need to install [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/). It is an android emulator for pc, where you can install Whatsapp as well as other apps.
After installation, just follow instructions.

Note: You need an active mobile number.